# Hibernation in Status Menu Not Working

Tags: 18.04, hibernate, gnome-shell, statusbar

First of all hibernation via the command

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

works fine from command line on my newly installed Ubuntu 18.04.

I've a fine gnome extension called **Hibernate status button** which displays an **hibernate button** in my system menu, as depicted in this image

[image: status bar]

But when I click on it is hibernating and power down, but when I start up the next time it opens with a completley new session.

Has anyone  a working solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/add-hibernate-option-ubuntu-18-04/), you did right things except that you have to create the file
`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`
You can do it by copy/paste the following in a termnial

```
sudo tee -a /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla << END1
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
END1
```

Comment: I already have this file, except the last line with **END1**. Is this an error by you since the original script of your refered link also has not the last line?

Comment: nope END1 rely to the tee command i used to create the file

Comment: I have this file but it doesn't work. I've also changed the kernel to recognize the right swap partition (resume=/dev/sda3). However, very strange, since pm-hibernate works fantastic. Maybe it is a kernel problem. My ubuntu crashed randomly, setting the kernel parameter **intel_idle.max_cstate=1** made it stable.

Answer (score 0):

This is with Nvidia's NVHDA issues ... meaning sound via HDMI. Here are the steps for the command-line - should you have Nvidia's NVHDA as I do:

If I manually disable the audio output:

```
sudo tee /proc/acpi/nvhda <<< OFF
```

I'm then able to get it to sleep. I then have to turn it on again on resume with:

```
sudo tee /proc/acpi/nvhda <<< ON
```