# Hibernation using Power Button : 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management, hibernate, gnome-shell-extension

I followed the complete process in the [Ubuntu Handbook Methood](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-17-10/) to enable hibernate on Ubuntu 18.04. Then installed *s2disk* `sudo apt install uswsusp`. Currently, the command `sudo pm-hibernate` works perfectly *including resumption*. However, when done using the **Power button**, hibernation process fails to resume. Also, the [Hibernate Status Button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047101/hibernation-in-status-menu-not-working) is not working.

I noticed that the command `sudo pm-hibernate` **works**. However, the command `sudo systemctl hibernate` **doesn't**. Looking at the messages on the screen after pressing **Power Button**, it seems that `pm-hibernate` is not initiated. Instead instructions corresponding to `sudo systemctl hibernate` are getting executed, which fails during resume.

I am looking for a method to get `sudo systemctl hibernate` working **or** instructions to switch to `pm-hibernate` on pressing **Power button**.

Note: this issue is exactly the same as an [Old Ubuntu Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056326/ubuntu-18-hibernation-using-the-power-button) which is unanswered. I am adding this as a new question so I can respond to further-info requests.

**EDIT:**

I party solved the question using config on [the ARK wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uswsusp#With_systemd) and its debian version [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386837/256774). Now, systemd uses s2disk *(pm-hibernate uses s2disk)* to hibernate. Thus,`sudo systemctl hibernate` works and so does hibernate on **Power** button press. ***However, why aren't the native systemd hibernate commands working?***

Answer (score 2):

Found part of the answer.

Use the config on [the ARK wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uswsusp#With_systemd) and its debian version [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386837/256774). Then, `systemd` would start using s2disk *(`pm-hibernate` uses s2disk)* to hibernate. This will get`sudo systemctl hibernate` working, and dependent features like *hibernate on **Power** button press* will automatically work. *However, why the native systemd hibernate commands aren't working, is something still unknown.*